# Showing different gender icon based on user's gender

Tags: swift

I currently have the following to show gender:

```
var user: User? {
    didSet {
        nameTextField.text = user?.username
        genderLabel.text = user?.gender
    }
}
```

I know only to show the text label, how can I make it to show "male icon" or "female icon" based on the users' (current user and the other users' profile) genders?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to create a view with a label and imageview?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Right now the users can see “male” or “female” from their userProfile page. However, I want them to see an image instead (e.g. male user will see a male icon instead of seeing “Male”).

Comment: Change the UILabel to an UIImageView and set its image accordingly

Comment: Yeah. My question is that I don’t know how to set the image accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have not provided enough context, however, I will attempt to help you with this based on four assumptions:

1. You are setting an initial value for the `user` object since property observers require an initial value to be set
2. You are using a property observer here knowing that `didSet` will not fire when the initial value is set
3. You have a UIImageView property representing the gender icon
4. You have icons for all the genders you wish to represent in your asset catalog

If you have an imageView called something like "genderImageView" for example, you would set it in this property observer like so:

```
var user: User? {
    didSet{
        nameTextField.text = user?.username
        genderLabel.text = user?.gender
        var image = UIImage()
        if user?.gender == "male" { // for example
           image = UIImage(named: " name of male gender icon in asset catalog")
        } else if user?.gender == "another gender string" {
           image = UIImage(named: "name of this gender in your asset catalog")
        } // more else-if blocks or else block here to support all genders you want
       genderImageView.image = image
    } // forgot your closing bracket here, or not showing enough information about this property observer
}
```

Comment: Great! It works! a little correction: var image = UIImage() Thank you very much!

Comment: or `let image: UIImage`  without the parentheses and remove the second condition `} else {`

Comment: @LeoDabus if you read the comment on the else-if condition you will see that I put it in there for reference because I did not want to assume Verve is dealing with only 2 genders :) also  I disagree about your UIImage comment, although I made a typo using a ":" instead of "=", we need the image to have a value because we set it for sure after the conditional block, I actually tried to lookup if the image property of UIImageView is an optional (thought it was) but it is not.

Comment: @富源Verve I'm glad it worked! Sorry for the typo, I did mean `var image = UIImage()`, just edited it now